# Cancel Current Command but Save to History

Tags: linux, bash, command-history

In bash we can prepend a command with `#` and insert the non-executed command into our history. Is there a way to achieve similar behavior through some shortcuts or keybinds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `vi` (`set -o vi`) mode, you can hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> and then <kbd>#</kbd>; that will prepend the current command with `#` and enter it -- harmlessly into the shell as a commented command and also into the command history.

Comment: Thank you, this works for me.

Comment: If anyone knows a shortcut for emacs mode, feel free to edit it in!