# How to retrieve command from history after using Ctrl+C to clear the current input line

Tags: bash

When I am entering some command, often I need to run a different command. I once saw in a video where they hit ^C then later retrieved that command from history.

The answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140741/how-to-save-a-command-you-entered-without-executing-it?noredirect=1#) (2nd paragraph) also talks about this exact behaviour I am looking for. But doesn't say how to make it work.

Quoting the answer->

> Alternatively, and this is particularly useful if you are in a nested command, such as a while or for loop, hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, which adds the command to history without executing it and clears the line, so you can then recall it using the shell's history mechanism when you are ready to use it.

I know we can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>, but I am looking for this specific solution.

I went over all these sources:

https://superuser.com/questions/563939/save-command-to-history-without-executing-in-bash
[How to save a command you entered without executing it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140741/how-to-save-a-command-you-entered-without-executing-it)
[Remember a half-typed command while I check something](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10825/remember-a-half-typed-command-while-i-check-something)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35807653/how-do-i-add-a-command-to-bash-history-without-executing-it
https://superuser.com/questions/555310/bash-save-history-without-exit
[Cancel Current Command but Save to History](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/550669/cancel-current-command-but-save-to-history)
[Running a subshell from the middle of the current command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/506070/running-a-subshell-from-the-middle-of-the-current-command)
[Coming back to a command I have partially written](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191910/coming-back-to-a-command-i-have-partially-written)

Comment: The answer you quoted works only for *multi-line* commands. `bash` saves a *string* to history only after `Enter`. So I don't think bash can save commands directly to history like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shells do not typically enter a <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>-cancelled command into the history.

I can't find anything in the GNU Bash or GNU Readline documentation about enabling a behavior whereby cancelled commands would be put into the history anyway.

If you're typing a command and realize you need to run another one first, then jump to the start of the line and comment out your command with `#`. Then hit Enter to dispatch it. Commented lines **are** put into the history, so you can later recall it, delete the comment character and keep working on it.

Comment: Useful key binding for commenting/uncommenting: [here](https://superuser.com/a/1823184/432690).

Comment: Thank you for keybindings.